# During a bosh deploy, where are blobs synched from?

Tags: cloud-foundry

This was the question I had a day or two ago and it was surprisingly difficult to answer, so I will post here, with answer, inviting anyone to augment my answer or provide a better one.

The github repositories for [vcap-services](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-services) and [cf-release](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release) don't contain the blobs for those services; for example, the redis-2.6.2.tar.gz file, while referenced in [cf-release/packages/redis26/spec](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/blob/master/packages/redis26/spec), isn't anywhere in the repositories.  That is as it should be - those tar files don't belong up in github.  During a `bosh deploy` they are synced into my cf-release/blobs directory.  But from where?

Answer (score 1):

The question came up for me when I was getting ready to put into a github repository all of the bits and pieces for a custom system service we were adding to our internal cloud foundry cloud.  Where should I put the blobs so that my colleague can clone and deploy our cf-release without ugly steps to drop blobs into certain places?

As already mentioned, during a `bosh deploy`, you can see the blobs syncing. Well, if you are using the cf-release with few changes, it will pull them down from a public blobstore (at this time of writing and Atmos one) found at http://blob.cfblob.com.  You can find this configuration in the [cf-release/config/final.yml](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/blob/master/config/final.yml) file.

The answer to the question of where to put OUR blobs is a bit more involved and it seems from [this](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/bosh-users/9YuPz1RCFuA) that "composite releases" are part of the answer - but that's another topic.